# jQuery: IE8 margin collapses when using slideUp()/slideDown()

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I've uploaded a test file here:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2201804/IE8test.html

If you click on the "Click me" divs, you'll see the "Feedback" divs appear using slideDown(). Clicking a "Click me" in another box slides the currently showing feedback up and slides down the appropriate feedback.

In IE8, after the slideUp()/slideDown() actions are complete, the margin between the boxes collapses.

Is this a problem with jQuery's animation or a display bug in IE8?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> overflow: hidden;

should do the work :)

Comment: Had the same problem in IE8, adding overflow:hidden to the element that grows/shrinks solved it!.

Comment: This worked for me too. Can anybody explain WHY this works?  Is it just an IE bug?  Does IE9 do the same thing?

Comment: I too would like to know WHY it works ... what does overflow:hidden have to do with vanishing margins?

Comment: I guess this is because IE8 needs a block formatting context on sliding element with margin. There are another properies which you can use to workaround this, but overflow:hidden just seems to be most suitable. You can read about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Block_formatting_context)

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to explicitly tell which element you are adding this rule to? Thank you.

Comment: Adding it to the `.assessment` div in the example seems to do the trick.  I had a accordion type thing where it was `.accordion` > `.panel` > `header`/`section` (`section` is the thing that `slideUp()`/`slideDown()` is applied to, and `.accordion` is the one with the margin).  Adding `overflow:hidden;` to `.accordion` worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a solution for you using margins, but if you replace margin with padding, IE8 will play along. In your case, you would need an extra container div, because you are already using the padding and you have a background colour set.

So your solution could look like this:

```
<div class="assessment">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="question">
...

.assessment { 
  padding-top: 20px; 
  background: transparent; 
}

.assessment .inner {
  background-color:#DDDDDD;
  border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
  color:#555555;
  display:block;
  padding:10px 0;
  text-align:left;
  width:100%;
}
```

Cheers
tj

Answer (score 2):

Just updating this old thread with my solution as I wasn't able to solve the problem using CSS.  I used the callback function of slideToggle to focus on the document body because I noticed that clicking anywhere else on the page seemed to cause a reflow of the DOM and the margins came back.

```
.slideToggle(
    500,
    function() {
        document.body.focus();
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

I was still having issues with margins disappearing using this "overflow: hidden" suggestion, and decided to simply disable the slideUp/slideDown functionality entirely in IE8 by overriding the 'default' jQuery functionality with a custom function that would still show or hide the element, but **only** when IE8 was being used.

To achieve this, I used an [IE conditional comment](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/internet-explorer-conditional-comments/) to append a class to the html element, like so:

```
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie8"><![endif]-->
```

Then, I defined the following function in my javascript to override the slideUp/slideDown function, like so:

```
(function($) {
    // disable slideDown/slideUp in IE8 due to margin removal issue
    if ($('html').hasClass('ie8')) {
        $.fn.slideDown = function() {
            return this.show();
        };        
        $.fn.slideUp = function() {
            return this.hide();
        };
    }
})(jQuery);
```

And that solved the issue for me, as far as I'm concerned.  Hope this helps!