# Margin collapses using jQuery slide effects on IE8 only

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem similar to other threads where IE8 collapses my margins when using slideUp() and slideDown() effects via jQuery.

I am building an accordion, as seen on http://www.airtypehub.com/clients/webllp/practice.html.

The CSS declarations that collapse are (both the dt and dd):

```
.practice #accordion.live dt {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.practice #accordion dd {
    background: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 20px 20px 1px;
}
```

The JavaScript (excerpt) is:

```
$('#accordion').addClass('live');
$('#accordion dd:first').slideDown().prev().addClass('open');
$('#accordion dt:not(.open)').corner('5px').live('click', function() {
    $('#accordion dt').removeClass('open').corner('5px');
    $('#accordion dd').slideUp();
    $(this).addClass('open').next().slideDown();
});
```

I have tried several things in advance, including:

- The oft-cited method of adding overflow:hidden to the CSS declarations above, as well as adding it to the container #accordion.
- Adding zoom:1 to all of the above CSS selectors.
- Changing my margin-bottom's to margin-top's.
- Creating a callback on the slideDown() method in the JavaScript to add CSS to the element via jQuery, trying both the overflow and zoom properties.

So far I've had no luck with any of the above remedies. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See my solution for this at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31212831/1330629

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I think this will fix the problem:

```
.practice #accordion dd,
.practice #accordion dt,
.practice #accordion dl{
   width:100%;
   float:left;
}
```